# Can't fit entire HTML content in iframe

Tags: javascript, css, angular, html

I'm having an issue with a website I'm working on - mainly that I can't seem to fit an HTML doc into an iframe in a way that it takes up the entire page. I'm also using angular to get the html document, which is what the src is. This is what the page looks like right now :

1) https://gyazo.com/f5cb06ede5fc0b6da99f49dfd8e32d5f
2) https://gyazo.com/c9ad51e9bfaa12fedc4e1c2dbcbb7b42

Notice that there is a scroll bar, this is my issue. How do I get rid of the scroll bar and display the content of the web page such that it extends fully without the scroll bar? Here is my code for reference:

```
 <iframe id="content" [src] = "recipeHTML | safe">

 </iframe>

      <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript'>

    $(function(){

        var iFrames = $('iframe');

        function iResize() {

            for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
            iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';}
            }

            if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) { 

            iFrames.load(function(){
                setTimeout(iResize, 0);
            });

            for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
                    var iSource = iFrames[i].src;
                    iFrames[i].src = '';
                    iFrames[i].src = iSource;
            }

            } else {
            iFrames.load(function() { 
                this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
            });
            }

        });

</script>
```

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things that you can look at. First off, in a CSS document, including the following should eliminate the appearance of a scroll bar in the iframe;

```
iframe{
overflow:hidden;}
```

However - and from here on out I'm doing a bit of guesswork as you haven't really given us much about the source WRT how it's coded at all - you could try restricting the size of the source page by constraining everything on it within a div with a specified size, that way when the page is called via the iframe you can explicitly tell the iframe to have the same height and width using the width="" height="" attributes of the tag (or including them in the CSS).

Answer (score 0):

if you need to change the dimensions of your iframe depending on its contents you will need some Javascript to do so.

You need first to answer if the iframe is on the same domain or if it is cross-domain loaded.

It is easier on the same domain as described here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fit-iframe-to-content/ and looks very similar to your attempt.

And a bit more intensive on cross-domain: https://css-tricks.com/cross-domain-iframe-resizing/

But the best solution would may be either live all contents together in one CMS or a Server-Proxy (PHP or whatever) that loads the HTML of the iframe and displays it on your site as normal content so no problems are left.

greets,

tom